# Is there some method of analyzing why a program is very slow to start?

Tags: performance, startup

I've bought a used computer with an NVME drive which seems very quick, but when I start some programs on it they are very slow.

Once they start, they run fine, but the time it takes them to appear on the screen is very delayed.

e.g. Firefox 112.0 is slow to start the first time, and even when I run a different profile from the current session it is still slow to start, when in fact because the main binary is already running the new session should be faster.

*pavucontrol* is a program which starts up almost instantaneously on my other systems which are much older, but on this computer it is also slow to start.

For instance I have a laptop with an i7-4600 and an old desktop with a Core 2 Quad Q9650 and these programs startup faster on them. So it can only be disk read problem or something else is going on before the programs start.

These are the computer specs:

CPU: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-8365U CPU @ 1.60GHz

RAM: 16GB

Hard disk: 512GB NVMe SSD

Output of `df -h`

```
/dev/nvme0n1p4                                         452G  132G  298G  31% /
/dev/nvme0n1p3                                         362M   99M  245M  29% /boot
/dev/nvme0n1p2                                         511M  5.8M  506M   2% /boot/efi
```

Output of `free -h`

```
               total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:            15Gi        11Gi       338Mi       1.7Gi       3.7Gi       2.0Gi
Swap:          8.0Gi       5.1Gi       2.9Gi
```

The system is using more RAM than earlier because I have more Firefox windows open. Earlier values were much lower.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us more about the machine. First of all, what operating system have you installed? What is the actual hardware? Should we assume a laptop? Which one? How much RAM? How large is the disk? How many disks and what is installed where? Is `/` on the NVMe drive? How about the various `bin` dirs? Do you have swap? What kind? How much? Show us the output of `df -h`. Are other programs faster? Where are they installed?

Comment: You could try `man strace`, `top` and many other utilities.

Comment: Do you have Ubuntu installed? Firefox is slow to start on Ubuntu due to it being installed as a snap package.

Comment: yeah, the good news is that what you describe sounds more like software performance problem than related to storage speed.

Comment: How much RAM and swap do you have?  `free` will show. You probably need a swap file (or partition), 1.0x to 1.5x the RAM size. Read `man free mkswap swapon fstab sudo`. Please [edit] your question to add whatever information you get. Don't use Add Comment, or you'll classify yourself as "Does Not Follow Instructions (DNFI)", and I'll ignore you. I view DNFIs as unhelpable.

Comment: @terdon et al I have updated the question with more info. There is only one hard disk on the system, none of the executables are on the path.